# Name 'ssh_client' is not defined

Tags: python, django, paramiko, django-class-based-views

I have function: `connect_dev()` and I wanna call it from the class `config_static()`, but an error appears:

> name 'ssh_client' is not defined

So this is my view.py file:

```
class config_static(View):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formm = NacmForm(request.POST or None)
        ipform = IpFormset(request.POST)
        upform = UploadForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        userValue = formm['username'].value()
        passValue = formm['password'].value()
        destination = str(request.POST['destination'])
        prefix = str(request.POST['prefix'])
        gateway = str(request.POST['gateway'])

        if ipform.is_valid() and formm.is_valid():
            simpanForm = formm.save()

            for form in ipform:
                ipaddr = form.cleaned_data.get('ipaddr')
                vendor = form.cleaned_data.get('vendor')
                networks = str(destination+"/"+prefix)
                netmask = IPNetwork(networks).netmask
                collect_config = "<b>Configure on "+str(ipaddr)+" | vendor = "+str(vendor)+"</b></br>"

                try:
                    connect_dev(self, ipaddr, userValue, passValue)
                    config_read = str(vendor.sett_static_routing)
                    array_read = config_read.split('\r')
                    output_line = ""

                    for line in array_read:
                        new_line = re.sub(r'\n','',line)
                        if new_line != '':
                            config_send = eval(new_line)
                            collect_config = collect_config + config_send+"</br>" 
                            print(config_send+" ini config send")
                            try:
                                stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(config_send+"\n")
                                time.sleep(1)
                                results = stdout.read()
                                print (str(results))
                            except:
                                try:
                                    remote_conn.send(config_send+"\n")
                                    time.sleep(1)
                                    results = remote_conn.recv(65535)
                                    print (results.decode('ascii'))
                                    # print (results)
                                except:
                                    print("error paramiko")
                    messages.success(request, collect_config)

                    ssh_client.close()
                    simpanIp = form.save(commit=False)
                    simpanIp.connect_id = simpanForm
                    print (simpanIp)
                    simpanIp.save()

                    simpanForm.save()

                except Exception as e:
                    error_conf(request, collect_config, "</br>Exception in connecting to the server")
                    print (e)

        return HttpResponseRedirect('routing_static')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formm = NacmForm()
        ipform = IpFormset()
        return render(request, 'config/routing_static.html', {'form': formm, 'logins': Connect.objects.all(), 'ipform': ipform, 'status': self.status})
```

and there is my function:

```
def connect_dev(self, ipaddr,userValue,passValue):
    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_client.connect(hostname=ipaddr,username=userValue,password=passValue,look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False, timeout=5)
    remote_conn=ssh_client.invoke_shell()
    shell = remote_conn.recv(65535)
```

When I run it I get an error:

> name 'ssh_client' is not defined

I tried with an added parameter :

```
def connect_dev(self, ssh_client, ipaddr,userValue,passValue):
```

and in the class config_static(View):

```
connect_dev(self, ssh_client, ipaddr, userValue, passValue)
```

The result is still the same.

Comment: So how did you do it? What errors are you getting?

Comment: sorry, i edit my problem